# How to display the value of heatmap with conditions

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using heatmap.2 and trying to fill the value of each cell with different color under different condition. However, when I am using ifelse in notecol, the result doesn't fit the data at all. Is there a way to fix this?

```
heatmap.2(
  fig4,
  Rowv = F,
  Colv=F,
  dendrogram = "none",
  margins = c(5,7), 
  col = new2, 
  cellnote = fig4,
  notecex = 0.6,
  notecol = ifelse(fig4 > 500, "white", "black"), 
  keysize = 1,
  symkey = FALSE,
  density.info = "none",
  trace = "none"
)
```

I am expecting the value larger than 500 can be white, else will be black. However, only some irrelevant value on the diagonal line was displayed in white.

Comment: try `c(ifelse(fig4 > 500, "white", "black"))`

Comment: Thank you. but I found "notecol= "function is reading a vector from bottom to the top, so you have to flip the matrix upside down and then transform it into a vector rowwisely.